# Ubuntu 14.10 showing less space in "home" folder than it should

Tags: directory, home-directory, ram

The "home" folder has 100GB. With all my stuff there, it should've had 90GB at most.

But now it's displaying 34GB available?

I downloaded some source files from Github, but deleted them afterwards.

Any idea what my cause this?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean, your home partition is 100GB in size?

Comment: You should try `baobab`. Baobab will help you understand where your disk space is going. It creates a nice table and diagram of any folder (including root filesystem ). It also shows you the size of each directory and subdirectories and so on. The program is also known as 'Disk Usage Analyzer' https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Baobab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd>) and run `df -h`. The `-h` comes from *human readable*, to print sizes to traditional size unit.
For me for example above command print:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6        14G  4.3G  8.9G  33% /
udev            989M  4.0K  989M   1% /dev
tmpfs           399M  864K  398M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            998M  752K  997M   1% /run/shm
none            100M   36K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1       183M   87M   86M  51% /boot
/dev/sda7       168G   46G  114G  29% /home
```

That because is a partition. The canonical way to find folder size is (`-s` for *summary*):

```
du -hs /home/myusername
```

BTW, if you need to make some free space the best way I found is to use [**ncdu**](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) (*ncurses disk usage viewer*) which it is like a *Disk Usage Analyzer* (*baobab*) alternative for command line.

Comment: I found my answer later. It was the /.trash hidden folder. Had to get rid of it. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: That folder is your Paperbin. If you delete something it will not be deleted from disk. It will be moved to this folder instead. You could empty trash bin *the traditional way* by right-clicing or in command line (nasty way) with `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*` (-rf is the same as --recursive --force). Even better with trash-cli installed, you can run trash-empty command
.